# Multiple NsTimer view transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

i am trying to using a Nstimer view transition on multiple view controllers but if i copy and paste it i get an error saying Duplicate declaration of method . how would i fix it ? please explain in your answer how to do this . i found out how to do this from this link .

http://x-code-tutorials.com/2013/06/19/nstimer-trigger-uiviewcontroller-transition/

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startTimerMethod];
}

- (void) startTimerMethod {
    transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) transitionView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition" sender:self];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startTimerMethod];
}
- (void) startTimerMethod {
    transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) transitionView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: The issue is obviously that you've implemented these three methods twice. I'm unclear, though, as to what you are trying to do. What do you mean "transition on multiple view controllers"? Can you more clearly describe the desired effect? (As an aside, if you implement `viewDidAppear`, that method should call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`. I know you just used the code sample from that link, but that's incorrect: You should always call `super` rendition of the `viewDid` and `viewWill` methods.)

Answer (score 0):

You have copy and paste below three methods two times let it define or declare single time:-

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

    -(void) startTimerMethod

   -(void) transitionView
```

Comment: The code which you have pasted there are total 6 method. So just look your method. You have declared two times.